# Dismiss ngb-modal outside modal controller

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap

I've created a component with the content of a modal that I want to display on other multiple components.

modal.component.html:

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
  <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="dismissModal()">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">...</div>
```

modal.component.js:

```
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private modal: NgbActiveModal
  ) { }

  dismissModal() {
    this.modal.dismiss();
  }
}
```

And I'm calling this content in other parts of my site, such us:

header.component.html:

```
<button (click)="openModal(myModal)">
    Open Modal
</button>

<ng-template #myModal let-modal>
  <app-modal-content></app-modal-content>
</ng-template>
```

header.component.ts:

```
openModal(content: string) {
  this.modalRef = this.modalService.openModal(content, { centered: true });
}
```

The modal shows up correctly, but when I try to dismiss the modal by pressing `X` it does not work, because the modal reference is in the header component. How could I dismiss the modal if I'm opening it from other component?

Answer (score 0):

The modal.component.ts file should inject the `NgbActiveModal` service in order to close the modal.

In the modal.component.ts file constructor:-

```
import { NgbActiveModal, NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

export class ModalComponent {
  constructor(public modal: NgbActiveModal) {}
}
```

Comment: Should it work only injecting the `NgbActiveModal`? I tried that and nothing happens...

Comment: You need to call the NgbActiveModals close method as well https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/api

Comment: I edited my question, adding some changes on my code with your recommendations, and also needed to add `NgbActiveModal` to my app providers for avoiding some compilation errors, but still the modal doesn't close when pressing the `X` button...

Comment: Is the function dismissModal() getting called? If yes, try modal.close() as well